# how to listen to events in github actions for entire organization without changing the repos in the organization?

Tags: github-actions

my situation is that I can not add yaml workflows in each repository but I can add one repo and I wish to know if there's a way to add some workflows in that repo and get triggered if other repos in the organization have some events like push ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is currently built in, but I would love to see something like this.  The Documentation lists [all available events.]
(https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) None of these events is at an organizational level.

The only way I know of to get all events for an organization is through building a [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/about-creating-github-apps/about-creating-github-apps).   An App on a server you provide can listen to events from all repositories it has access to.
A GitHub application can be setup with specific repositories it can access, or it can be setup for "All Repositories."
 
The key is you will have to something outside of GitHub listening for a web hook to make the decision.

If you want, then you can call a workflow by [creating a workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) through the REST Api.